# Load new page with CI route

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I'm new to CodeIgniter and it's routing is confusing me, I'm trying to simply load a different page (I have separate controllers and views for each page).

I have the following code:

```
<li class="active"><a href="/homepage">Home</a></li>
```

My routes.php is:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "homepage";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['homepage'] = "homepage";
```

Going to

```
http://demo
```

loads the homepage page (I have virtual hosts configured in Apache), but clicking the Home link gives me

> The requested URL /homepage was not found on this server.

Comment: Why do you define two routes with the exact same controller? Simply give your `$route['homepage']` a different controller / method

Comment: Why did you change the default_controller? And did you create the default controller? And if you did, the last route is redundant.

Comment: @rpm - I want the homepage to appear whenever just the domain name is typed and when the homepage link is clicked. if I give the homepage route a different controller, won't I just have 2 identical controllers?

Comment: @repox = I changed the default controller so the homepage appears when the domain is navigated to, don't I have to specify which page to load when the homepage link is clicked?

Comment: @SteB The default controller only tells the application what controller should be used, when the URI segments doesn't point to any other controller. If you change the default controller to `homepage` your default controller file should be named as such. When users visiting your website, going to www.example.com and www.example.com/homepage will show the exact same controller file.

Comment: @repox - That's what I'm aiming for, but typing in www.example.com/homepage brings up "requested URL /homepage was not found".

Comment: And if you type example.com/index.php/homepage?

Comment: @repox - Yes, that works! Now I'm really confused, isn't index the default method on a controller?

Comment: @SteB Yes it is. But the index.php file is the bootstrap file where all requests goes through. See the [manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) for clarification.

Comment: how about `site_url('homepage')` or `site_url('')` on your `href=''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to try:

- Check `mod_rewrite` is installed
- Check **httpd.conf** is configured to `AllowOverride` from .htaccess

Remember that you don't need to explicitly state all routes either, CI will do the work on pointing to the name specified in the URL to the controller within the `application/controllers/` folder.